# How to have a circle in the nav bar for the first frame of one section?

Tags: beamer, navigation, circles

In a `beamer`document using the 'Singapore' theme I have some subsections that are one slide long. I noticed that in this case the "circle" in the "navigation bar" does not appear.

Here is one little example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usetheme{Singapore} 
  \title{Title}
  \author{Author}
  \definecolor{macouleur}{RGB}{51,110,23} % vert moyen
%\definecolor{fondtitre}{RGB}{243,246,93}  % vert fonce
\definecolor{coultitre}{RGB}{50,200,17}  % marron
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=coultitre, bg=white}

  \begin{document}
}


\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}



%first frame
  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  % New section
      \begin{frame} \frametitle{1st Frame}
     \section{Section 1}
     \subsection{Sub 1}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide] 
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}\frametitle{2nd Frame}
    bla bla bla
  \end{frame}


  % All it's okay if I uncomment it :
%      \begin{frame}\frametitle{Sub2}
%  \subsection{Sub2}
%  This is the beginin of sub2.
%  \end{frame}

% I don't see any circles for this subsection...
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Sub2}
  \subsection{Sub2}
  This is sub2.
  \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Conclusion}
\section{Conclusion}
 Conclusion.
 \end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me to get the navigation bar right please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because you're putting `\section` and `\subsection` commands *inside* the `frame` environment. Moving them out will get the circles back.

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Singapore} 
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\definecolor{macouleur}{RGB}{51,110,23} % vert moyen
%\definecolor{fondtitre}{RGB}{243,246,93}  % vert fonce
\definecolor{coultitre}{RGB}{50,200,17}  % marron
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=coultitre, bg=white}

\begin{document}
% \setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}

%first frame
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

% New section
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{1st Frame}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide] 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{2nd Frame}
bla bla bla
\end{frame}

\subsection{Sub 2}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Sub2}
This is the beginin of sub2.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Conclusion}
Conclusion.
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]